# JSON format display in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, formatting

I've done PHP and was able to get JSON format to display nicely using

```
<pre></pre>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how would you apply something similar with Ruby on Rails?

In my views document, I have this:

```
<%= @recent_media_items.to_json %>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<pre><%= @recent_media_items.to_json %></pre>
```

? `<pre>` is HTML, not PHP...

Comment: oh duh! haha that makes sense. I did try that, but its outputting it weird. its widening my page very extensively and near the end of scrolling right, there's only bits of json, and its not even formatted properly? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying [CodeRay gem](https://github.com/rubychan/coderay). It will do all the work for you. Just send to it your JSON and you'll get nice, colorized output:

```
html = CodeRay.scan("{\"Hello\":\"world!\"}", :json).div
```

or in your case

```
<%= CodeRay.scan(@recent_media_items.to_json, :json).div %>
```